# Replace variable with its value inside HTML without <?php ?>

Tags: php

Here is the situation. I have 2 files

content.php

```
<?php $my_var = "this is a variable"; ?>
<h1> php{my_var} </h1>
```

index.php

```
<?php include "content.php" ?>
```

The result should be:

```
<h1>this is a variable</h1>
```

I know how to work with `preg_replace_callback`. But I don't know how can I change `php{my_var}` with the value of `$my_var`.
All the logic should happens inside the `index.php`.

**Edit**

index.php

```
function replace_pattern($match)
{
    what should I write here
}
echo preg_replace_callback("/php\:\{(.*)\}/", "replace_pattern", $Content);
```

**Edit 2**

Variables are not declare in the global scope

Comment: Have you tried using echo to write it to the HTML?

Comment: 'know how to work with preg_replace_callback'. Then show us what you have tried. And why don't you want to use `<?php echo $my_var ?`> instead?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php the examples here might help you figure this out.

Comment: What syntax is this? `php{my_var}`? I've never seen it.

Comment: if you do not want to use `echo` (what i do not understand), you can use `preg_replace`. Create a regula expression to get out the variable name from php{my_var}, and replace it with `$$preg_matched_name;`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: i think this is his own template system. i think the design is not so well.

Comment: @lolka_bolka it does not work because $my_var is in the different file

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I can not use echo and I want to know is there any way to do this without using echo.

Comment: @EEliya Sure. You can use `return` instead, or `print` if you want, or you can write directly to `stdout`, either way, they're all just  stream wrappers, the same way that `echo` is.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I can not use <?php ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the added question-mark in the regular expression to make it less greedy.

```
$my_var = 'Hello World!';

// Get all defined variables
$vars = get_defined_vars();

$callback = function($match) use ($vars)
{
    $varname = $match[1];
    if (isset($vars[$varname])) {
        return $vars[$varname]; // or htmlspecialchars($vars[$varname]);
    } else {
        return $varname . ' (doesn\'t exists)';
    }
};
echo preg_replace_callback("/php\:\{(.*?)\}/", $callback, $Content);
```

Demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ax15-bpyw

Comment: Well, the variables are not in global scope because of chance of overwriting

Comment: @Eeliya then you need `use` within your `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: I've edited my answer, this one is working in a different scope

Comment: I have tried your solution but unfortunately it did not work. It only works if I declare my variable in global scope

Comment: Can you call `get_defined_vars()` in the same scope as you defined the variables and pass the result of that (`$vars` in above code) to the scope where you define the callback?

Comment: the variable is in the `content.php` and I call `get_defined_vars()` inside `index.php`.

Comment: And how do you parse `content.php` do you use `include('content.php'), or did you use `file_get_contents('content.php')`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63051/discussion-between-eeliya-and-peter-van-der-wal).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$my_var = "this is a variable";
$string = '<h1> php{my_var} </h1>';
$pattern = '/php{(.*)}/i';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);
$varName = $match[1];
$newString= preg_replace($pattern, $$varName, $string);
echo $newString;
```

But, warning!
In this case, i assume, if the code is `php{somethin}`, then there should be a `$something` variable. I used dynamic variable name. If you want to use only `$my_var` then use like  this:

```
$newString= preg_replace($pattern, $my_var, $string);
```

Comment: The variable is in the other file and also its not in global scope, so this approach will not work

Comment: It doesn't matter. What i wrote just an example. When you use the `preg_replace`, you can use the `preg_replace_callback`. I've just show, how to find and replace your variable name.